# On backspace, `bash read -e` also deletes same-line printf (preexistent) text

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, readline

I use `printf "input: "; read -e`. I type something then I press `Backspace`. When reaching the last character, this deletes the `input:` part together with it. `Backspace` doesn't misbehave if I hadn't typed anything before or if I used simple `read` (no Readline).

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `bash` 4.4 on OpenBSD. If you're using `bash` you could also try `read -p 'input: ' -e`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I reproduced with `bash` 4.3.38 on `Ubuntu` 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Could you please confirm what shell you are using? The `read` in `zsh` also has an `-e` option but with different semantics from `bash`.

Comment: I can reproduce it with `bash` 4.4.12, not with `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `read -e` calls the readline library. Which gives access to several editing tools that a plain `read` does not have. However, it assumes an "empty line".

A workaround to this problem is to give something (like an space) to avoid the "empty line" assumption:

```
printf 'input:'; read -e -p ' '
```

But since that is using the `-p` option already, it might be simpler to write:

```
read -e -p 'input: '
```

Comment: This is the more direct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5):

`read` in `bash` is a builtin command. `read -e` uses the `bash` full-screen editing via the `readline` library (i.e. it understands how to go back to the previous line, move the cursor left and right through the inputted text, etc.). It may use cursor addressing codes to optimize the output to the screen.

However it expects that the cursor is at the beginning of the line when it begins, and sometimes it's faster to clear the whole line when removing the input than to remove the individual characters. This is what is messing up your prompt, which moves the cursor to the right without bash knowing about it.

The same thing can happen when using terminal escapes in your prompt (e.g. to set a colour, or to set the terminal title). For this purpose `bash` has special escapes to indicate which bytes don't move the cursor.

You should use `read -p 'input: ' -e`, the `-p` option for prompting is specially made for this.

Comment: readline isn't ***full-screen*** (it only handles a special case of single-line editing).